# Compute the center of $PB(H)P$, where $P$ is a projection

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P$ be a projection on $H$. I guess that the center of $PB(H)P$ is $\Bbb C P$.

Is there any method to compute the center of $PB(H)P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard basic von Neumann algebra theory. Given a von Neumann algebra $M\subset B(H)$ and a projection $p\in M$, then when we consider $pMp\subset B(pH)$ we have
$$
(pMp)'=pM'p,\ \ \ Z(pMp)=pZ(M)p.
$$
You can find this, among many places, in Proposition 5.5.6 in Kadison-Ringrose.

Comment: In proposition 5.5.6, there is a statement: $E'$ is a projection in $R'$, what does $R'$ denote by?

Comment: The commutant. Seriously, you'll get absolutely nowhere with von Neumann algebras if you don't know the most very basics. You are asking questions about spectral measures and Borel functional calculus, about affiliated operators, and you don't know what the commutant is?

Comment: I thought it was another von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Sorry, please forgive my foolness.

Comment: No need to apologize. But for real, I don't know who you are or why you ask about this stuff. But if you are a graduate student somehow getting into operator algebras, you need to get more familiar with this stuff. . I know that prime is used for many things in different areas. But in von Neumann algebras, it is always used for the commutant. Besides the fact that otherwise neither the statement nor the proof would make any sense. If you read any first chapter on von Neumann algebras this will be immediately clear.

Comment: Thanks very much. Would you mind giving me a hint on the follwing question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861516/closed-and-densely-defined-operator-which-is-affiliated-with-a-von-neumann-algeb

Comment: I posted a sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To compute the center of $PB(H)P$, first observe that $PB(H)P$ is isomorphic to $B(PH)$.

Comment: How to construct the isomorphism? Is it $PTP \mapsto  PTP$?